# How to rename legend in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I change the 0 and 1 values in this particular legend to 'No' and 'Yes' respectively?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.contourf(x1, x2, regr.predict(np.array([x1.ravel(), x2.ravel()]).T).reshape(x1.shape), alpha=0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red','green')))
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(x_set[y_set == j, 0], x_set[y_set == j,1], c = ListedColormap(('black','white'))(i),label=j)
plt.legend()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1ZEB.png)

Comment: `plt.legend(["Yes", "No"])`?

Comment: It says "Legend does not support 'Y' instances.
A proxy artist may be used instead." and the legend just disappears.

Comment: May you provide sample data points that you used for this plot?

Comment: @amin The data is from here: https://github.com/AvaisP/machine-learning-programming-assignments-coursera-andrew-ng/blob/master/machine-learning-ex2/ex2/ex2data1.txt

Comment: Did the code solve your problem?
As I see, I need the whole previous code to re regenerate x1, x2, and y_set.

Comment: @amin Yes, it did solve the problem. I also tried importing mpatches, which also solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your sloution:
Just you need to detrmine labels for `plt.scatter(..., label=['No','Yes'])`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.contourf(x1, x2, regr.predict(np.array([x1.ravel(), x2.ravel()]).T).reshape(x1.shape), alpha=0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red','green')))
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(x_set[y_set == j, 0], x_set[y_set == j,1], c = ListedColormap(('black','white'))(i),label=['No','Yes'])
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
yes_instance = mpatches.Patch(color='white', label='Yes')
no_instance = mpatches.Patch(color='black', label='No')
plt.legend(handles=[yes_instance, no_instance])
```